# Is there a way to mix known transforms in Famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

is there a good way to mix two known Transforms? i.e.

```
 var transform = Transform.mix(Transform.scale(2,2,2), Transform.rotate(1.4, 1.4,1.4))
```

and mix them into one transform matrix?

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for is called `Transform.multiply` which can be found here on [github](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/master/src/core/Transform.js#L79) it takes two transforms and makes them into one. And yes order matters in Matrix Multiplication.